# "Как минимум", обособление

Tags: пунктуация

Берется ли в запятые "как минимум" в середине предложения? "В нем было(,) как минимум(,) два метра роста".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Наречное выражение *как минимум* в **середине** предложения не является вводным (поскольку имеет обстоятельственное значение, т. е. является членом предложения) и не требует обособления: *В нем было как минимум два метра роста.* Если же эти слова стоят в **конце** предложения, они обычно обособляются как вводные: *В нем было два метра роста, как минимум.*

Answer (score 1):

С двух сторон выделяется запятыми в середине предложения, потому что это вводное слово, содержащее оценку меры того, о чем говорится:
*В нем было, как минимум, два метра роста.* (см.: Розенталь Д.Э. и др. СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ, параграф 99)

Answer (score 1):

Запятыми не выделяется. У Розенталя в параграфе "Сравнительный оборот" можно почитать.